# Bending moment and Shear force

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Do bending moment and shear force of a beam depend on it's cross sectional dimentions??
Since all the diagrams which I have draw so far don't involve any cross section details. So I think they do not depend on them and don't do any influences on the shear force diagrams and the bending moment diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do bending moment and shear force of a beam depend on it's cross sectional 
>   dimentions??

I never underestimate the power of experiment, and that indeed, physics and all of science is rooted deeply in experiment. Is it easier for me to snap a foot-long twig or the one foot high stump of a big tree that sticks out of the ground after someone has chopped it off, and what's different?

Yes, of course, the cross sectional dimensions matter. It's proportional to the moment of inertia, which you can find at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But sir when we're drawing shear force diagram and the bending moment diagram, we don't take those dimensional details into account other than the length right? The deflection indeed is affected by the cross sectional details and Young's modulus.

Comment: Of course you're right that the deflection is proportional to the force, and to $L^3$/Young's modulus. But it is also inversely proportional to the area moment of inertia, which scales roughly like the square of the cross-sectional area. So it is dramatically lower for a beam with greater cross-sectional area.

Comment: @TimeVariant I quite didn't understand the dependency of bending moment on the cross section. Bending stresses developed depends on the moment of inertia of the section i.e the cross section. But when we calculate the bending moment the cross section isn't gonna come into picture. After all its still the moment of force right?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why bending moment of a beam depends on the cross-section is that: the weight of the beam varies with its cross-section. In a typical textbook bending moment diagram, the beam member is assumed to be weightless. But in reality, an additional uniformly distributed load is placed on the beam to cater for its weight.